# Retrieve emails from postfix using ruby 2.5.1 - imap authenticate failure

Tags: ruby, postfix-mta

I am trying to retrieve emails in my rails app using [Net::IMAP](https://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.5.1/libdoc/net/imap/rdoc/Net/IMAP.html) (Ruby 2.5.1). The emails are located on the same server as the app (Ubuntu 16.04 & Apache2) under one of the users.

I am able to connact using `imap = Net::IMAP.new('localhost')`

But got stack on the [authenticate](https://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.5.1/libdoc/net/imap/rdoc/Net/IMAP.html#method-i-authenticate) part: `imap.authenticate('LOGIN', 'username', 'password')`, As the doc pointing I checked my capability and I found missing the nessery “AUTH=LOGIN” or “AUTH=CRAM-MD5”.

My question is how to fix this? how to make postfix have those mechanisms?

**My Postfix conf:**

```
alias_database = hash:/etc/aliases
alias_maps = hash:/etc/aliases
append_dot_mydomain = no
biff = no
home_mailbox = Maildir/
inet_interfaces = all
inet_protocols = all
mailbox_command =
mailbox_size_limit = 0
mydestination = $myhostname, example.com, mail.example.com, localhost.example.com, localhost
myhostname = pay-per.co.il
mynetworks = 127.0.0.0/8 [::ffff:127.0.0.0]/104 [::1]/128
myorigin = /etc/mailname
readme_directory = no
recipient_delimiter = +
relay_domains = lists.pay-per.co.il
relayhost =
smtp_tls_loglevel = 1
smtp_tls_security_level = may
smtp_tls_session_cache_database = btree:${data_directory}/smtp_scache
smtpd_banner = $myhostname ESMTP $mail_name (Ubuntu)
smtpd_tls_cert_file = /etc/ssl/certs/ssl-cert-snakeoil.pem
smtpd_tls_key_file = /etc/ssl/private/ssl-cert-snakeoil.key
smtpd_tls_loglevel = 1
smtpd_tls_security_level = may
smtpd_tls_session_cache_database = btree:${data_directory}/smtpd_scache
smtpd_use_tls = no
transport_maps = hash:/etc/postfix/transport
virtual_alias_domains = hash:/etc/postfix/mydomains
virtual_alias_maps = regexp:/etc/postfix/virtual
virtual_mailbox_domains = lists.pay-per.co.il
```

10x!

Comment: Please post your postfix configuration `postconf -n`

Comment: So you're using postfix for smtp, but what service stores the emails? Dovecot?  That is where you need to configure the login services for the imap/pop3 connections.